# Too many comments automatically deleted when closing as duplicate

Tags: bug, comments, duplicate-questions

Sequence of events:

- I started the process of closing a question as a dupe.
- The system adds the "Possible duplicate of..." comment on my behalf.
- Somebody adds a comment, tagging me.
- I respond with an additional comment.
- The question finally gets closed, due to other people's votes.
- The "possible duplicate" comment gets automatically deleted **and the additional comment I made too!**

At least this is what seems to have happened on this specific question: [SMD diode part number from marking code](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383860/smd-diode-part-number-from-marking-code?noredirect=1#comment940534_383860). My additional comment has been restored by a diamond moderator after I asked why it could have been deleted (see [chat log](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45796996#45796996)), but it has been missing between the time the question has been finally closed, and the time I asked for clarification on the moderator chat.

I don't think this is expected behavior. Shouldn't the system only delete the "possible duplicate" comment it added automatically, but not those I made myself afterwards?

(Or maybe I am entirely mistaken and the delete was not even due to the "possible duplicate" comment mechanism at all?)

Comment: Not really a bug. To be on the safe side, the dupe mechanism deletes any comment with the word "duplicate" and **link to any question** when the question is closed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, I understand I just had bad luck there. My comment had the word "duplicate", and linked to another post, although I wasn't pointing a dupe to the original post at all. But the heuristic seems strange anyway. I just feel like the system is removing useful information.

Comment: Well, ideal solution is to mark auto comments as such behind the scenes (another db table column?), then delete only the auto comments, and leave any other comment alone.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree this would be much cleaner, and would also solve most of the problems mentioned in the post you proposed as a dupe. Not sure about the difficulty of implementing this on SO side, though. I bet they'd prefer spending that time on other features/fixes.